# Public member 'Value' on type 'Decimal' not found - Removing last two characters

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to take the last two decimals off my number that I am pulling from SQL Server.

It comes out like this:

```
4790.2000
```

I want it to be:

```
4790.20
```

I tried this:

```
txtBoxVisaTotalBank.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("BANK_VI").String.Format("{0:N2}", 10)
```

But I get this error:

> Public member 'Value' on type 'Decimal' not found.

Comment: try txtBoxVisaTotalBank.Text = Math.Round( dt.Rows(0).Item("BANK_VI"), 2)

Comment: Thanks MAC but it displays 4790.00 instead of 4790.20, it is missing the .20

Comment: probably because your "BANK_VI" is integer or String

Comment: So what do I do? The column is saved as Money in the SQL Server.

Comment: try this>> txtBoxVisaTotalBank.Text = String.Format("{0:N2}", Double.Parse(dt.Rows(0).Item("BANK_VI")))

Comment: Didn't work.  Now it displays: 4,707.00

Comment: change double to decimal...it would be like Decimal.Parse

Comment: can you check the value of dt.Rows(0).Item("BANK_VI")?
what do you mean by that??

Comment: oh, so the last code worked??? what was wrong then?

Comment: My browswer cahce was not updating so it kept displaying the same value.  This code works: txtBoxVisaTotalBank.Text = String.Format("{0:N2}", Decimal.Parse(dt.Rows(0).Item("BANK_VI")))

Comment: oh great then...can i post that as an answer and can you accept it for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txtBoxVisaTotalBank.Text = String.Format("{0:N2}", Decimal.Parse(dt.Rows(0).Item("BANK_VI")))
```